# Highcharts Get color on column on click

Tags: java, colors, highcharts, series

I have a column chart. On clicking one of the vertical bars, I display another chart.  I want the second chart to have the color of the vertical bar I clicked on.

Note that, I have NOT set the color manually in highcharts and I do no wish to set it manually either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the point object's click handler:

```
       point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                   alert($(this.graphic.element).attr('fill'));
                }
            }
        }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/am5Xr/).